# How many iterations to reach the sequence?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

Let's define a function \$f\$ which, given a positive integer \$x\$, returns the sum of:

- \$x\$
- the smallest digit in the decimal representation of \$x\$
- the highest digit in the decimal representation of \$x\$ (which may be the same as the smallest one)

For instance:

- \$f(1)=1+1+1=3\$
- \$f(135)=135+1+5=141\$
- \$f(209)=209+0+9=218\$

We now define the sequence \$a_k = f^k(1)\$. That is to say:

- \$a_1=1\$
- \$a_k=f(a_{k-1})\$ for \$k>1\$

The first few terms are:

```
1, 3, 9, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99, 117, 125, 131, 135, 141, 146, ...
```

### Challenge

Given a positive integer \$x\$, you must return the smallest \$n\$ such that \$f^n(x)\$ belongs to the sequence. Or in other words: how many times \$f\$ should be applied consecutively to turn \$x\$ into a term of the sequence.

You can assume that you'll never be given an input for which no solution exists. (Although I suspect that this can't happen, I didn't attempt to prove it.)

You may also use 1-based indices (returning \$n+1\$ instead of \$n\$). Please make it clear in your answer if you do so.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Examples

- Given \$x=45\$, the answer is \$0\$ because \$x\$ is already a term of the sequence (\$a_6=45\$).
- Given \$x=2\$, the answer is \$3\$ because 3 iterations are required: \$f(2)=2+2+2=6\$, \$f(6)=6+6+6=18\$, \$f(18)=18+1+8=27=a_4\$. Or more concisely: \$f^3(2)=27\$.

(These are the 0-based results. The answers would be \$1\$ and \$4\$ respectively if 1-based indices are used.)

### Test cases

```
Input : 0-based output

1     : 0
2     : 3
4     : 15
14    : 16
18    : 1
45    : 0
270   : 0
465   : 67
1497  : 33
```

Comment: If you are going to use the \$f^n\$ notation you might as well just define the sequence in terms of it in the first place. \$a_n=f^n(1)\$.  I think it lowers the overhead to only do things one way.

Comment: Can we output '1-based' instead of '0-based' indices: that is, output for 1,3,9, and so on is 1, and output for 18 is 2, etc.?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen That seems reasonable. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @WheatWizard I've added the alternate notation. Not everyone may be familiar with functional powers however, so I think it's better to keep the verbose version as well.

Comment: This could also work as a "pure" sequence challenge, if we haven't had it already.

Comment: It appears as though neither of these sequences (the digit sum one, or the number of iterations) are on OEIS: [digit sum](https://oeis.org/search?q=9%2C+27%2C+36%2C+45&language=english&go=Search), [# of iterations](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+0%2C+15%2C+14&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Since every number in the range 100-117 eventually reaches the number 159 by repeated iteration, the same is true if you add arbitrarily many 1s at the beginning of each number.  Hence, the sequences starting at any two points must eventually meet.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

```
$‚€λDZsßO}`.i1k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f5VHDrEdNa87tdokqPjzfvzZBL9Mw@/9/EzNTAA)

```python
$‚            # pair 1 and the input
  €           # for each k of those two values
   λDZsß++}   # calculate the infinite sequence given by f^n(k):
    D         # duplicate the previous value
     Z        # take the maximum digit of the copy without removing it from the stack
      sß      # swap to the copy and get the minimum digit
        O     # sum previous value, maximum digit and minimum digit

`             # push both infinite sequences seperately on the stack
 .i           # for each value in the sequence starting with the input:
              #  is it contained in the other (non-decreasing) sequence?
   1k         # print the index of the first 1
```

Comment: -2 bytes by removing the `S` and changing the `++` to `O`. Nice answer, btw!

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 15 bytes

*Edit: -5 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
V£₁1₁
¡S+o§+▲▼d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X/YocWPmpoMgZjr0MJg7fxDy7UfTdv0aNqelP///0cb6hjpmOgYApGFjompjpG5gY6JmSlQwNI8FgA)

1-based output.

```
¡S+o§+▲▼d       # helper function ₁:
¡               # generate infinite sequence by repeatedly applying:
 S+o§+▲▼d       # function f:
 S+             # add the input to  
    §+▲▼        # sum of the max and the min of
   o    d       # the digits of the input
   
V£₁1₁           # main program:
V               # index of first truthy result of ...
 £              # getting the index (or zero if absent) of 
  ₁1            # the infinite sequence of helper function starting with 1
    ₁           # in the infinite sequence of helper function ₁ starting with the program input
```

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X/YocWPmpoMgZjr0MJg7fxDy7UfTdv0aNqelP///0cb6hjpmOgYApGFjompjpG5gY6JmSlQwNI8FgA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks a LOT!  I'd always glossed-over ```£``` without really understanding what 'list is supposed to be sorted' meant or was good for...  now I finally understand!

Comment: "An Husk".....??

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 45 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹η≔⁰ζＷ⁻θη¿‹ηθ≧⁺Σ⁺⌊Ｉη⌈Ｉηη«≧⁺Σ⁺⌊Ｉθ⌈Ｉθθ≦⊕ζ»Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/NCsIwEITP9ily3EAEC4JIT@KpYKXoE9Qam0ASmz@Vis8eE3so4snbfsPMLNOyxrTXRoRQqt67vZcnakDjIttYyzsFOUFsogVBQ6Q744IiqLjyFnRyYMQvCHbUWmAE6chV04@hA@@Yg1p4S9DRy8@VolxG2DbWQYyT6H98KUlLn6mwFD2z2R99@qdPj31p11QEpWoNlVQ5eh53vbLacOXGzIBxEUK@XK/C/Cbe) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `x`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start with `a=1`.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Start with `n=0`.

```
Ｗ⁻θη
```

Repeat until `x=a`.

```
¿‹ηθ≧⁺Σ⁺⌊Ｉη⌈Ｉηη
```

If `a<x` then calculate `a=f(a)`.

```
«≧⁺Σ⁺⌊Ｉθ⌈Ｉθθ
```

Otherwise calculate `x=f(x)`, ...

```
≦⊕ζ»
```

... and increment `n`.

```
Ｉζ
```

Output `n`.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 109 bytes

(or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 95 bytes** replacing both `function` appearances with `\`)

```r
function(x,`!`=function(n)n+sum(range(n%/%10^(0:log10(n))%%10))){while({F=F+1;i=1;while(i<x)i=!i;i-x})x=!x;F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3fCoIwFAbw@55CCWEHi7b8V67d@hhhRLMDNsGSBuKzr01t5@73ncN3eiOFkYO6f7BTRO/qsBaeClT8Hl6kv6nmQVR0iBi9Elq2XcOo3UJkAwAYv09sH2SsRBUzjoLxJcCLBhQhctzrCbQINa8mIwmDbeCmDOhGkqNXYpV6scySrbbMHU@e7jb7a@4p6MxFaZ6tyou551w42yeJ@QE)

Returns 1-based result.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>104</s> <s>86</s> 82 bytes

*-2 thanks to @emanresuA and @Shaggy, and another -2 from @tsh (with an honorable mention for @m90 :p)*

```
r=x=>(f=x=>x+Math.min(...x+="")+Math.max(...x),g=y=>y<x?g(f(y)):y>x)(1)&&r(f(x))+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchBCoMwEAXQu7gIfwgOBAptF5Mb9BBBarRYU6LIBLx7tKWbt3ivsIWly@NnbbdbrVlUPKIU8cXrvpdWjYlA/321j7AO/B5nMLNaaRr6V9BfEaHQiSNjMnqcYV3t0ryk6clTishwl/uVqB4)

Comment: [85](https://tio.run/##LchBCoMwEADAv3gIuwQXAgXbw@YHfcQiGhVrShTZgH@PWnqZw0yyy9qm8bvV@7OUxMoeAmf22etx5FqNCQD9/Wrfsg30GRcgImG1VYX/E/0dImS8cGhMgh4U0brSxmWNc0dzDJDAPV4NYjkB) by putting x+'' in a variable.

Comment: @emanresuA, [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##LchBCoMwEAXQu7gIfwgOBAptF5Mb9BBBarRYU6LIBLx7tKWbt3ivsIWly@NnbbdbrVlUPKIU8cXrvpdWjYlA/321j7AO/B5nMLNaaRr6V9BfEaHQiSNjMnqcYV3t0ryk6clTishwl/uVqB4) ;)

Comment: @Shaggy Ooh, clever!

Comment: `r=x=>(f=x=>x+Math.min(...x+="")+Math.max(...x),g=y=>y<x?g(f(y)):y>x)(1)&&r(f(x))+1`

Comment: Also 82: `f=x=>x+Math.min(...x+="")+Math.max(...x),r=(n,a=1)=>a>n?r(f(n),a)+1:a<n&&r(n,f(a))`

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 100 bytes

```scala
a(_)indexWhere(? =>a(1)takeWhile?.>=toSet?)
val a=Stream.iterate(_:Int)(x=>x+s"$x".min+s"$x".max-96)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vZnraF4UTAquZYeOreMAUQ)

Pretty simple solution. `a` is a function that makes an infinite list of the sequence, given a starting number. We make a sequence starting at `x` using that, and find the first index where an item is inside the sequence starting at `1`. Since the sequence can only be added to, it's monotonic and therefore safe to only check the elements which are less than or equal to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 114 bytes

```c
d;s;m;x;f(n){for(s=m=n,x=0;n;n/=10)d=n%10,m=d<m?d:m,x=d>x?d:x;s+=m+x;}g(n){for(s=1;n>s;s=f(s));s=n<s?1+g(f(n)):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/RbsIwDHznK6xKSAkNooUBAxN4mPYVKw8oSbtqa0BNpUVD/fV1LpQyFsWJc76zc2qcKdU0Gh0W6DFllp/TY8mcLKQVXkZo0U5kHHEt7TCORCH1ptjpdUFFvfWUeXShLEKPdXZXx2i3Dp1MmeOcbrtxuzjMWDuAryOsm9xWUBxyyzicB0CrBSrjKve2BwnnWMBUwJOAuI1nSueELCNKFvMWXS1r7IXGn4yqjL5qiTQjSktbUAiILnuxJHx2V41AvRv1YcqrKkj86zTxqxeKeSDg73sWdDKyB6ydmFttPMki7NINuPzbHFN2@wufdMCoRxDC8MK@me6NU6er@Ut5jw/VkqoZq/gjagjtff@XnUqipCwYahhvgc6hSyyZqgSUovddSmn2Xdt6UDc/Kv08ZK4Zf/0C)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>128</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>98</s></sup> 94 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n+int(min(`n`))+int(max(`n`))
g=lambda n,s=1:n>s and g(n,f(s))or n<s and-~g(f(n),s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/BboMwDL3nKywujTVXKjCgRU0v075inVQGgaKtLiI50B3268yh1bTIT/J7fpZfhps/XzmZ59Z8VZePpgIu@alnry896xOfEO@smu5MdX9GciYu@eCg4gY6zdRqh3gdgfeLtv7pdKsZyeHsrfMODOiYICF4JogDttJmohQbafIsqLsClZ0GW3vbhAWZpKKHWS4g2CyVF6KnqOqzrT/tGJzRcXpNjtPuRZBFBP95GqFqJZonsNAzfPeDXjIJfxzDUoG8kLLTHhcyjPL5sLSC9QFWBOKHx8k3a4x7n38B)

Saved 17 bytes thanks to [gsitcia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95116/gsitcia)!!!

\$0\$-based return value and returns `False` for \$0\$.

Comment: [111](https://tio.run/##LU/basMwDH33V@gtNnUhadekC7iwl8JgfzAGzRK5MU2VYLus289nclohgc7R0W36jf1Im3m2Zmiu310DVNPKUZRXR/JEJ6UeqLk/kOjQwlmS9ibXwRSqFvDTuwGBDqEOxsqgBHiMN0@ss5KU9qtCB@Us0DoADgHBzxFDDGBAFho2Gl40FCn2nO6YqXJOyl1iXysl8D5hG7FLDVzZMp9qJYeGfPGyYn6rRNtje0GflNnx7f0j05CNl0wJO3qIGhAcwZ@b5HIB4@fo9Ahbuukso1rA5Pn31JTB@gA8ifXwXPCJxoSv@R8) since s doesn't need to be a list

Comment: Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
;1DṀ+ṂƊ+Ɗ€</¦⁻/Ð¿Ḣ€QL
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields a positive integer (using the 1-indexed option).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//OzFE4bmAK@G5gsaKK8aK4oKsPC/CpuKBuy/DkMK/4bii4oKsUUz///8xNDk3)**

#### How?

Perhaps there is a more terse approach, but I have not thought of one yet.

Starts with the input and \$1\$ and applies \$f\$ to the minimum of the two while they are unequal, then counts the number of values visited from the input to the final value.

```
;1DṀ+ṂƊ+Ɗ€</¦⁻/Ð¿Ḣ€QL - Link: integer, x
;1                    - concatenate a one
               Ð¿     - collect while...
             ⁻/       - ...condition: reduce by not-equal
         €  ¦         - ...do: sparse application...
          </          -       ...to indices: reduce by less-than
        Ɗ             -       ...action: last three links as a monad, f(v)
  D                   -         decimal digits
   Ṁ+ṂƊ               -         minimum plus maximum
       +              -         add (v)
                 Ḣ€   - head each (all the values we got from x's side)
                   Q  - deduplicate
                    L - length
```

---

##### 0-indexed alternative

Also 21 bytes:

```
;1DṀ+ṂƊ+Ɗ€</¦⁻/Ð¿nƝSḢ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 62 bytes

```julia
!a=a+sum(extrema(digits(a)))
>(x,a=1)=x<a ? 1+(!x>a) : a!=x>!a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczLCsIwEIXh/TxFgpsZKqVj01aLiQ8iLgYsktIW6QXy9lEpwbP6Nv/pt8ELhxi1WMmWbcQurHM3Cj79y68LChGBw3AUy2TDVdRNcYY6OCHVKtE2OC3xPftpHaYcc4d3YPXboVUFnBJLMIlcAZvkGvicDKb6h02RaOpqZ918w0uz/5XwIIof)

#### Explanation

- `!` is the function `f`
- `a` is `fⁿ(1)` (we don't care about n)
- `1+(!x>a)`: if `x<a`, we compute `f(x)` and add 1 to the result
- `a!=x>!a` is parsed `a!=x && x>!a`

  - returns `false` if `a==x` (false is equivalent to 0) and doesn't evaluate the second part
  - if `a!=x`, computes `x>!a`, which means we compute `f(a)` and return `x>f(a)`